How to prove that the area of a continuous function $ f\left( x \right) $ enclosing a curved trapezium with the x-axis can be n-equalised
First is a simple problem for a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$ with $f(x)>0$. Prove that: on the interval $[0,1]$, there exists $x=x_0$ such that $x=x_0$ bisects the area of the curved trapezium with $y=f(x)$ as the curved side.
Obviously one can prove the above conclusion by constructing the function $$g\left( x \right) =\int\limits_0^{x}{f(t)dt}\int\limits_{x}^1{f(t)dt}$$ and then using Rolle's theorem.
More generally, for such a continuous function $y=f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ with $y > 0$,  is there always at least one set of coordinate sequences $$x=\left( x_1,x_2,...,x_n \right)$$ $$0<x_1<x_2<...<x_n<1$$ such that the $(n+1)$ sets of curved trapezoids corresponding to the partition are equal in area.
That is, prove that there exists $x=\left( x_1,x_2,...,x_n \right)$ such that $$\int\limits_0^{x_1}{f(t)dt}=\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}{f(t)dt}=...=\int\limits_{x_n}^1{f(t)dt}$$
Right now I don't know how to construct functions to use the median theorem to try to prove propositions and it's not clear if a structure like $$\int\limits_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}{f(t)dt}$$ is a multivariate function, can you provide some help in constructing a function and interpreting the significance of the integral?
